How to Use the "keyword" Targeting Key in Google Ad Manager Tag (Google Publisher Tag)?
I'm implementing Google Ad Manager Tag (Google Publisher Tag) on my website and I want to utilize the targeting feature to display ads based on specific keywords related to the content of my pages. I've heard about the "keyword" targeting key, but I'm unsure about how to properly use it. However, I'm struggling to find detailed documentation or examples specifically addressing the usage of this key.
Could anyone point me towards official documentation or reliable sources that explain how to effectively use the "keyword" targeting key in the context of Google Ad Manager Tag? I'm looking for confirmation of its functionality and any best practices or examples provided.
Any references or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
I attempted to implement targeting using the 'keyword' key in Google Ad Manager Tag by using the following code snippet:
adSlot.setTargeting('keyword', ['basketball']);
However, I'm uncertain if this approach is correct, as I couldn't find detailed information in the official documentation regarding how the 'keyword' key functions or any specific guidelines for its usage.
I'm seeking clarification on whether this implementation is valid and if there are any additional steps or considerations required for effectively utilizing the 'keyword' targeting key.

You should use the console to debug your adcalls and make sure the key "keyword" is having the value "basketball".

If yes : it means you are now able to target specific line items on
the value. Make sure to create the key in Ad Manager user interface
as fully detailed here.
If no : it means something went wrong. Look for specific message in
the console (see here).

Please note there are 2 levels of targetings : slot targeting & page targeting. A page targeting is available for all slots in the page. On the other hand, a slot targeting is only available within itself.
